# A Call of Duty to show how close we are to each badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, data-dump

In the *Call of Duty* online stats pages you see how far away from each challenge you are. You achieve small parts of each challenge just by playing the game, but when a challenge is within reach your behaviour changes and you concentrate on achieving it.

Can we have a similar set of stats for gaining new badges? The number you have got so far (or number remaining), then a little progress bar for scanning down the list more easily. If you can only get one instance of a badge then you could mark it as completed.

For example:

```
[125] [=   ] Copy Editor × 655         Edited 500 posts
[68]  [=== ] Stellar Question × 889    Question favorited by 100 users
```

You could add more badges for getting badges. E.g. Get all bronze badges, get all silver badges, getting a bronze badge 5/10/x times.

I bet analysing the data will show how the visitor behaviour has changed and it'll be a good way to increase traffic as well.

Comment: This is already available for selected badges, if you know where to look. The "badges for getting badges" idea has been brought up before, but Precognitive and Beta make it borderline pointless.

Comment: Vote-based badges like Great/Favorite/Stellar Question/Answer don't really have much of a "progress" towards them. In the vast majority of cases, you either get it or you don't. A post with 40 upvotes after the first week may never make it to 100, whereas posts can occasionally shoot from 0 to 100 in under 3 hours.

Comment: @PopularDemand: "*if you know where to look*" Yeah, that's the problem: where you have to look is not intuitive. I would expect them to be readily visible from the badge page.